# Capture audio from dock connector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm writing an app which captures audio from the mic input which works fine but I want to capture audio from the dock connector rather than the mic input. I know that pins 5 and 6 are audio inputs, so my question is from a software point of view, is this possible and would I just use the AudioToolbox framework functions as I am now?

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not possible for regular apps on stock OS iOS devices.  Inputs on the dock connector appear to be inaccessible from any app except when working under Apple's MFi program.  You have to contact Apple for any information on enrolling in this program, which may involve some paperwork.

Apples Camera Connection Kit might allow using USB microphones for input.  There are also some 3rd-party audio dock input products.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but surely the APIs used by the apps which use dock accessories must be public? All I need is to sample audio which must be a public API somewhere.